# Python 3 cannot import just installed module on Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pip, importerror

`pip3` failed to install the `Image` module, therefore I have followed an alternative procedure, but then Python cannot import the module.  Here is what I have done:

```
C:\Users\myuser>pip3 install --user Image
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

C:\Users\myuser>python3
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pip
>>> pip.main(['install','--user','Image'])
Collecting Image
  Using cached image-1.5.5.tar.gz
Collecting pillow (from Image)
  Downloading Pillow-4.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (1.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 323kB/s
Collecting django (from Image)
  Using cached Django-1.10.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting olefile (from pillow->Image)
  Using cached olefile-0.44.zip
Installing collected packages: olefile, pillow, django, Image
  Running setup.py install for olefile ... done
  Running setup.py install for Image ... done
Successfully installed Image-1.5.5 django-1.10.6 olefile-0.44 pillow-4.0.0
0
>>> import Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import image
```

instead.

The problem here is that the *name of package* is not always corresponding with the *name it's imported* in python.

Comment: You may use `pip list` in the command line to see what are really installed.

Answer (score 0):

I run:

```
 python3.4 -m pyinstaller labelme.spec
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyinstaller'
```

I use:

```
 pip3 list
```

Find the installed module name: PyInstaller
so at last:

```
python3 -m PyInstaller labelme.spec
```